# PHP connecting Oracle and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, oracle, select, insert

I' trying to get some data from Oracle via ODBC to mySQL database.
And then Insert some lines in mySQL database.
I manage to list the lines from ORACLE but fail to Insert into mySQL.

```
$time_start = microtime(true);

set_time_limit(10000);

//ligação ODBC ORACLE

$connect = odbc_connect("test", "test", "test");

$query = "select barcod, to_char(barfecgen, 'YYYY-MM-DD') as data, barnumuni, barcolnom, clicod from barcad where barcodreo = 1";

$result = odbc_exec($connect, $query);

$numOF = 0;

// Ligação mySQL

$con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","intranet");

if (!$con)

  {

  die('Erro de ligação mySQL: ' . mysql_error());

  }


mysql_select_db("bd_test", $con);


?>

 < table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="8" cellspacing="1">

    < tr class="cabecalho_tabela">

      < td bgcolor="#666666"><strong>#</strong></td>
      < td bgcolor="#666666"><strong>Ordem de Servi&ccedil;o</strong></td>
      < td bgcolor="#666666"><strong>Data entrada</strong></td>
      < td bgcolor="#666666"><strong>Kg entrada</strong></td>
      < td bgcolor="#666666"><strong>Artigo</strong></td>
      < td bgcolor="#666666"><strong>C&oacute;digo do cliente</strong></td>
    < /tr>
    <?php
 while(odbc_fetch_row($result)){

   $of1 = odbc_result($result, 1);//Ordem de servi&ccedil;o

  $of2 = odbc_result($result, 2);//Data de Entrada

   $of3 = odbc_result($result, 3);//kg entrada

   $of4 = odbc_result($result, 4);//Artigo

   $of5 = odbc_result($result, 5);//Cliente

   $numOF++;

  $minhadata = substr(odbc_result($result, 2), 0, 4);

  if ($minhadata == "2010") {

   $corlinha = "linha_tabela_alt";

   // insere registos

   $mysql_query = ("INSERT INTO bd_test.tb_reclamacoes (data_entrada, ordem_servico, cliente, kg_entrada, artigo) VALUES ($of2, $of1, $of5, $of3, $of4)");

  } else {

   $corlinha = "linha_tabela";
  }

   ?>

    < tr class="<?php echo $corlinha; ?>">
      < td align="righ t" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $numOF; ?></td>
      < td bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $of1; ?></td>
      < td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $of2; ?></td>
      < td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $of3; ?></td>
      < td align="center" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $of4; ?></td>
      < td align="right" bgcolor="#CCCCCC"><?php echo $of5; ?></td>
    < /tr>
    <?php
}
  ?>
  < /table>
<?php
odbc_close($connect);
mysql_close($con);
$time_end = microtime(true);
$time = $time_end - $time_start;
echo "Tempo de Script: $time segundos\n";
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If some of your fields are strings or dates (data_entrada, artigo, cliente) you should write this :

```
  $mysql_query = ("INSERT INTO bd_etmaganha.tb_reclamacoes (data_entrada, ordem_servico, cliente, kg_entrada, artigo) VALUES ('$of2', $of1, '$of5', $of3, '$of4')");
```

And even better, use `mysql_real_escape_string()` to ensure your strings will be correctly saved

Comment: ...and add proper error checking to your code, and quote specific error messages when posting a question, and strip out irrelevant information (i.e. all the HTML and Oracle code in the sample above)

Answer (score 1):

I tried this with succes:

```
 $query = ("INSERT INTO bd_etmaganha.tb_reclamacoes (data_entrada, ordem_servico, cliente, kg_entrada, artigo) VALUES ($of2, $of1, $of5, $of3, $of4)");
 mysql_query($query); // u forget to execute query
```